# loan to deposit ratio

Tags: banking

I'm straggling to understand why loan to deposit ratio could be greater than 1. According credit creation theory every creation of new loan is matched by creation of deposit, so assuming some additional deposits exist (for instance created by placing the currency at the bank account) loan do deposit ratio should be at most 1. In fact financial statistics provide evidence that for some credit institution ratio is greater than 1.

Any thoughts on this issue?? I would appreciate any help!!!

Comment: I can get a loan at this bank and then send the money to a different bank. Now this bank has a loan, and that bank has a deposit.

Comment: so countries (taking banking sector in aggregate) with LDR greater than 1 lend money to foreign entities?

Comment: You could have a financial institution which makes loans but does not take deposits (it funds the loans either from its equity funds or by borrowing from the market, and when a borrower wants money it send an amount to the borrower's account at another bank).  Or you could have a bank which does this in combination with traditional banking, with more loans in total than deposits.  There are risks here and with [Northern Rock in 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Rock#2007_crisis_and_nationalisation) it went badly wrong